# Return values in recursion

Tags: c#

My question "how do modern languages handle local variables and recursion?" comes from writing a file search method.  Basically,

```
public ArrayList getMusicFiles(string directory){
    ArrayList songpaths = new ArrayList();

    string[] localFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory);
    for(int i=0; i<localFiles.Length-1; i++)
        if(isMusicFile(localFiles[i]))
            songpaths.add(localFiles[i]);

    string[] localFolders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(directory);
    for(int i=0; i<localFolder.length-1; i++)
        getMusicFiles(localFolder[i]);
}
```

So, the problem is this will redeclare "songpaths" with every recursion.  In VB you can declare songpaths as static, which I think would solve this.  Is there a good C# way for me to not overwrite the ArrayList?

Comment: Why would anyone use `ArrayList` instead of `List<string>` here?

Comment: What exactly do you do with the `directory` parameter?

Answer (score 8):

Note that I am operating under the assumption that you meant to use the `directory` parameter in place of the `rootDir` class-level variable.

---

You have two options here.

## The hacky, but more-efficient way

In this case, you pass the list object through.  I am going to use `List<string>` instead of `ArrayList`.

```
public List<string> getMusicFiles(string directory) {
  var list = new List<string>();
  getMusicFiles(list, directory);
  return list;
}

private void getMusicFilesInternal(List<string> songpaths, string directory)
{
  string[] localFiles= System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory);
  for(int i=0; i<localFiles.Length-1; i++) {
    if(isMusicFile(localFiles[i])) {
      songpaths.add(localFiles[i]);
    }
  }
  string[] localFolders= System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(directory);
  for(int i=0; i<localFolder.Length-1; i++) {
    getMusicFiles(songpaths, localFolder[i]);
  }
}
```

## The less-efficient, but functional way

Return the list and aggregate the results each time you recurse:

```
public IList<string> getMusicFiles(string directory)
{
  List<string> songpaths = new List<string>();
  string[] localFiles= System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory);
  for(int i=0; i<localFiles.Length-1; i++) {
    if(isMusicFile(localFiles[i])) {
      songpaths.add(localFiles[i]);
    }
  }
  string[] localFolders= System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(directory);
  for(int i=0; i<localFolder.Length-1; i++) {
    songpaths.AddRange(getMusicFiles(localFolder[i]));
  }
  return songpaths;
}
```

You can also implement this using delayed execution, which is still not as efficient as the first example, but gives you much more flexibility with how you use the result:

```
public IEnumerable<string> getMusicFiles(string directory)
{
  string[] localFiles= System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory);
  for(int i=0; i<localFiles.Length-1; i++) {
    if(isMusicFile(localFiles[i])) {
      yield return localFiles[i];
    }
  }
  string[] localFolders= System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(directory);
  for(int i=0; i<localFolder.Length-1; i++) {
    foreach (var j in getMusicFiles(localFolder[i])) {
      yield return j;
    }
  }
}
```

This will return an enumerable that will perform the search operation *each time* you enumerate it, similar to how Linq queries work.  You can call `ToList()` on the result to execute the query and store the results in a list that you can enumerate several times without executing the query again.

If I clean up all of the code, the following is the variant I would probably choose to go with.  Your original code has several issues (you subtract one from the arrays' `Length` properties, even though this will cause you to skip the last element, and there are a few other typos).

```
public IEnumerable<string> getMusicFiles(string directory)
{
  foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory)) {
    if (isMusicFile(file)) {
      yield return file;
    }
  }

  foreach (var dir in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(directory)) {
    foreach (var musicFile in getMusicFiles(dir)) {
      yield return musicFile;
    }
  }
}
```

If you are worried about the performance of `foreach`, don't.  First of all, you should be coding for readability first and performance second, optimizing only when you find a bottleneck.  Second, when you use `foreach` on an array type, the compiler will turn it into an equivalent `Length`-based iteration rather than access the array through an `IEnumerator<T>`.

Comment: How did you come up with that in 2 minutes?

Comment: +1, but `Directory.GetFiles(path,"*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)` obviates the need for recursion.

Comment: Well in that case, [`Directory.EnumerateFiles(path,"*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) will also do it, but without buffering all the files.

Comment: @sixlettervariables If only it returned a delayed-execution `IEnumerable<string>`... I see your point, but if the directory structure is huge then that approach will actually turn out to be worse, as it will pull the entire file list into memory all at once.  This code, while a bit more complex, will pull in the files at each level one-by-one.  The only objects representing filesystem layout that are ineligible for collection at any point will be the `string[]` objects for each directory still being processed.

Comment: @cdhowie: your case will be less tolerant to larger structures than letting Win32 handle it under the hood. Ultimately if there are more files than can be handled in memory, both will die. The recursive version will die sooner.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: indeed, I added a a footnote to my own answer using that, but when you see `ArrayList` you start to lose hope.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I don't think that's accurate.  The function does not recurse until the array returned by `GetFiles()` is eligible for collection.  Only the arrays of directories currently being iterated are ineligible for collection at the time recursion happens.

Comment: @cdhowie: minus the large Array containing the data. I don't disagree that they both are bad and that EnumerateFiles is the only solution to the problem that doesn't suffer from early OOM.

Comment: @sixlettervariables In my preferred solution (see the last block of code) there is no "large array containing the data."

Answer (score 2):

You could opt to use an accumulator strategy, and foist the work to a helper function which requires the array be passed to it:

```
public List<string> GetMusicFiles(string directory)
{
    List<string> songPaths = new List<string>();

    GetMusicFilesHelper(directory, songPaths);

    return songPaths;
}

private void GetMusicFilesHelper(string directory, List<string> paths)
{
    string[] localFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
    for(int i = 0; i < localFiles.Length; i++) 
    {
        if(isMusicFile(localFiles[i])) paths.Add(localFiles[i]);
    }

    string[] localFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);
    for(int i = 0; i < localFolder.length; i++)
    {
        GetMusicFilesHelper(localFolder[i], paths);
    }
}
```

Another option would be to skip recursion all together and let [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) do the work for you:

```
public List<string> GetMusicFiles(string directory)
{
    List<string> songPaths = new List<string>();

    // TODO: pick a better search pattern
    string[] paths = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (string path in paths)
    {
        if (IsMusicFile(path))
        {
            songPaths.Add(path);
        }
    }
}
```

If you're on .Net 4.0+, this becomes a cakewalk with [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx):

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetMusicFiles(string directory)
{
    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .Where(ff => IsMusicFile(ff));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code's a bit hard to read, but anyway... I'd suggest writing a private version of the method which is actually used for recursion, and pass the ArrayList as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by passing in the current list - that way you can append the list in your recursion. Something like this...

```
public ArrayList getMusicFiles(string directory, ArrayList data, string rootDir) {
    string[] localFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(rootDir);
    for (int i = 0; i < localFiles.Length - 1; i++) 
        if (isMusicFile(localFiles[i])) 
            songpaths.add(localFiles[i]);

    string[] localFolders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(rootDir);
    for (int i = 0; i < localFolder.length - 1; i++) 
        data.AddRange(getMusicFiles(localFolder[i]));
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public ArrayList getMusicFiles(string directory, ArrayList songpaths){
  string[] localFiles= System.Io.Directory.GetFiles(rootDir);

  for(int i=0; i<localFiles.Length-1; i++) if(isMusicFile(localFiles[i]))
      songpaths.add(localFiles[i]);

  string[] localFolders= System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(rootDir);
for(int i=0; i<localFolder.length-1; i++) getMusicFiles(localFolder[i]);
```

And then you pass in a `new ArrayList()` when you first call the method.